# How to Check X amount of days back to check a column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two datasets

df1

```
 ID      Name   StartDate      EndDate      Team 
 101    Adam    1/2/2022      3/2/2022      Sales 
 101    Adam    3/2/2022      7/3/2022      Sales 
 101    Adam    7/3/2022      12/31/2022    Sales 
 102    Beth    4/20/2022     6/10/2022     Tech
 102    Beth    6/10/2022     8/10/2022     Advisor
 102    Beth    8/10/2022     12/31/2022    Advisor
 103    Carl    5/20/2022     8/25/2022     Sales
 103    Carl    8/25/2022     9/25/2022     HR
 103    Carl    9/25/2022     12/31/2022    HR
 .....
 150    Sue     3/4/2022      6/4/2022      HR
```

df2

```
RequestTeam   Manager_ID     Person_replaced  Request_Date 
 Tech           107                 Beth       7/10/2022  
Sales           137                 Carl       10/1/2022
.....
 Advisor        112                 Claire     11/22/2022
```

The Goal is to look x amount of days back from the time of the `Request_Date` (I am using 30 days back as an example) and see if the person that has been requested was apart of the new team. Using `StartDate` as the field of reference.

Desired Output

```
RequestTeam Manager_ID  Person_replaced  ID  Request_Date  Team_prior_Request  PriorDate
 Tech         107             Beth       101   6/10/2022       Tech            5/10/2022
 Sales        137             Carl       103   10/1/2022        HR             9/1/2022
```

First I merged the datasets together on `ID` made sure to convert the dates to a datetime for those that weren't already. Then I tried to create a new field that would show dates 30 days back by row. All code is below:

`df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on= "ID", right_on= "Manager_ID", how = "left")`

`df3["Request_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df3["Requested_Date"])`

`df3["days prior"] = df3["Request_Date"] - dt(days = 30)`

`df3["Team_prior_Request"] = np.where(((df3["n days prior"] <= df3["StartDate"]) & (df3["StartDate"] < df3["Request_Date"])), df3["Team"],df3['Request_Team'])`

I hope this is enough information, I am trying something new and trying to explain it right. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense, if your first step is to merge on ID/ManagerID, then the merge is empty. There is no match in the provided example.

Comment: @mozway Youre right sorry I should I thought it was inferred but the data does go down so all the IDs in the Manager Id column are in the ID column just not shown. Sorry for not explaining that

Comment: Please edit your example to be exact (and minimal), with the correct matching output ;)

Comment: I hope this helps if anything I may have to re ask the question.

Comment: No, a minimal example doesn't have `...`, it just has a few rows, but with meaningful data, just add the 107 ID in df1 for example, but ensure that the expected output is **exact**, not an approximation of what it would be **given the provided input**. I understand very well the logic, but you should provide an exact example to avoid any ambiguity and save everyone's time, and to help future readers understanding the logic.